# Typing Relay Connection model for TS/Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, types

*This question is more about Typescript in general, but it has an Angular part as well.*

I want to make a generic component for displaying 2many relations, and my model comes from graphql, following the Relay Connection standart, like this:

```typescript
type Node = {
  id: string;  
}

type Edge<T extends Node> = {
  node?: T;  
}

type Connection<T extends Node> = {
  edges?: Edge<T>[];  
}

type Tag = Node & {
    name: string;
}

type Comment = Node & {
    text: string;
}

type Post = Node & {
    comments: Connection<Comment>;
    tags: Connection<Tag>;
}
```

Now what I want to get in Angular:

```typescript
class Rel2ManyAwareComponent<T> {   
    model: T;   
    config: RelConfigCollection<T>
    ... 
}

class PostComponent extends Rel2ManyAwareComponent<Post>{
    
    config = {
        'comments': {
            connection: this.model.comments
            display: 'text'
        },
        'tags': {
            connection: this.model.tags
            display: 'name'
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

```html
<rel-2-many config="config['comments']"></rel-2-many>
<rel-2-many config="config['tags']"></rel-2-many>
...
```

```typescript
class Rel2ManyComponent {
    @Input config: RelConfig<any, any>;
    ...     
}
```

```html
<li *ngFor="let rel of config.connection.edges">
    {{rel[config.display]}}
</li>
...
```

and I want the config to be strongly typed.

I was kind of able to achieve it with:

```typescript
type RequireConnection<T> = T extends Connection<infer X> ? T : never;

type RequireEdge<T> = T extends Edge<infer X> ? T : never;

type ExtractArrayType<T> = T extends (infer U)[] ? U : T;

type RelConfig<T extends Node, K extends keyof T> = {
  connection: RequireConnection<T[K]>;
  display: {[s in keyof RequireEdge<ExtractArrayType<RequireConnection<T[K]>['edges']>>['node']]?: boolean};  
}

type RelConfigCollection<T extends Node> = {
  [K in keyof T]?: RelConfig<T, K>
}
```

However here are several problems:

1. IDE inside PostComponent checks typing correctly and shows errors, however does not provide autocomplete, unless you override generic declarations with explicitely typed ones.
2. I don't know how to actually get related model key as value, only as index, so my config looks like:

```typescript
    config = {
        'comments': {
            connection: this.model.comments
            display: {'text': true}
        },
        'tags': {
            connection: this.model.tags
            display: {'name': true}
        }
    }
```

and I'd like to remove this unnecessary level.

3. Rel2ManyComponent fails to recognize RelConfig.connection as a Connection, and treats it as any.
4. I'd appreciate any general advice about Angular generics best practices in case I'm doing it completely wrong.